# Difference in network driver .inf versions

Tags: windows-10, networking, command-line, drivers

what is the difference between "netwtw" versions packaged inside a network driver .exe
Each Network Driver package appears to contain the three following versions of the driver as a .inf file

Netwtw04
Netwtw06
Netwtw08

I'm trying to establish which one to install on a 64bit Windows 10 Dell laptop. Also which drivers to uninstall as there is a lot of outdated ones.

Are they equally the same, or is one better?
Are they all required, or just one?
I have tried doing a google on this but come up with nothing, just a vast amount of BSOD reports.

Happy to read through some K/B if someone has can locate the resources, or a simple summary would be great as well.

- This is a Intel driver, provided by dell, for a Dell Vostro Laptop.
- I know I can run the .exe, trying to install in remote background to prevent user disruption.
- Using pnputil tools to install the drivers to user devices.

Comment: You would have to compare the text document with one another. We can't tell anything based on the name of the files themselves.

Answer (score 0):

Driver packages for Dell, Lenovo, and I think HP, include a number of models in any one package (lest they go berserk with thousands of packages).

Use the Driver Download for your specific model and it will do the correct thing.

We have done this lots of times.

Comment: The laptop I am testing on has various editions already installed: Netwtw04 Netwtw06 Netwtw08.
I want to understand what the difference is, if it has relevance. The package is specific to the model of the laptop, but you have to pick on specific .inf file. So which one? how can I tell which is the appropriate .inf file...

Comment: I see multiple INF files in my package downloads and I let the package install the correct driver. Users do not have to pick the correct INF, and indeed the majority of users would not even understand what an INF file is. So just installing the package should work.